# Add Nsattributed string and string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, nsattributedstring

I having the Dynamic data, I load that data into tableview but these data having the mixing of Attributed and normal strings.

Here I getting the as "Tap here" ,I want to dilate that string with Blue colour and pick on that it need to open the url.

I write following code but it gives error.

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and
>   'NSMutableAttributedString'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "WhatisrewardsTableViewCell", for: indexPath)as! WhatisrewardsTableViewCell
        cell.imageview.image = images[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.titlelbl.text = tilenames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.desclbl.text = descriptions[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        let value = " here.".withTextColor(UIColor.disSatifyclr)

        if (cell.desclbl.text?.contains("tap"))!{
           // cell.desclbl.text?.attributedString
            cell.desclbl.text = descriptions[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] + value
        }

        cell.desclbl.addLineSpacing()
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: please share code which you have written till now.

Comment: I am trying to fetch the tap in all cells there after I add here with different color

Comment: let value = " here.".withTextColor(UIColor.disSatifyclr)

        if (cell.desclbl.text?.contains("tap"))!{
           // cell.desclbl.text?.attributedString
            cell.desclbl.text = descriptions[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] + value
        }

Comment: You can prepare method, which takes dynamic string as parameter and returns the Attributted string as per your requirement, and you have to use that attributted string to cell.desclbl.text?.attributedString object

Comment: Unrelated but do not use multiple arrays as data source. That's very bad practice and pretty error-prone. Use a custom struct or class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not append the NSAttributedString to String objects. I would suggest that you generate a normal String and then add the attributed parameters to it.

```
func prepareURLString() -> NSMutableAttributedString {

        let masterString = "To navigate to google Tap Here."

        let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: masterString)

        let formattedStringAttribute = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 51.0/255.0, green: 51.0/255.0, blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha: 1),
            ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

        let privacyPolicyAttribute = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .bold),
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
            NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: 1,
            NSAttributedString.Key.link: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
            ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

        formattedString.addAttributes(formattedStringAttribute, range: NSMakeRange(0, formattedString.length))

        let privacyPolicyRange = (masterString as NSString).range(of: "Tap Here")
        formattedString.addAttributes(privacyPolicyAttribute, range: privacyPolicyRange)

        return formattedString
    }
```

This function will return a attributed string which you can use however you want. With tableview you can pass some parameters and modify the cell's attributes strings. I have added a google link behind the 'Tap Here' and its showing the output like below :

[image]

I hope I got your question right and this helps you in some way.